# Ubuntu: Quickly reordering windows

Tags: ubuntu, window-manager

Is it possible to quickly reorder windows in Gnome Ubuntu? I often find myself with many maximized windows and needing to get 3 or 4 specific ones to the front of my display.

My solution now is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> * N and grabbing one of my windows each time. Is there a utility like the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> window picker that would allow me to grab all of the windows I need in one shot?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the work space switcher if I get you correctly .
I would suggest you use something like a Desktop 1,2,3,4 thing and keep the ones of a particular category in a certain desktop environment .

Comment: I do that, but I'm still pretty cluttered... I'd really love to have the window picker that stays active even after it brings a window to the front... if that makes any sense... I can settle for virtual desktops though.

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly which windows will be more important, you can right click their tab on taskbar, select "Always on Visible Workspace". Then whenever you only want to see those windows, switch to an empty workspace. You can also try superkey(windows key) + A to quickly pick a window among all workspaces.

Hopefully that helps.